# Get Controls of MDIChild

Tags: c#

I create a new MDIChild having a RichtTextBox:

```
Form myForm = new Form();
myForm.MdiParent = this;
RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
myForm.Controls.Add(rtb);
myForm.Show();
```

As there may be opened some other MDIChilds having no RTB in it, I want check if the ActiveChild has a RichtTextBox in it. I'm not sure how to do this...
Something like this in a try-catch (?):

```
foreach (Control control in this.ActiveMdiChild.Controls)
{
    // check if the control is a checkbox
    // make the richttextbox as an object so I can do strange things with it ^^
}
```

Could you please help me out?

Thx & Cheers
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the control is a `RichTextBox` by using the `is` operator:

```
foreach (Control control in this.ActiveMdiChild.Controls)
{
    if (control is RichTextBox)
    {
        RichTextBox rtfChild = (RichTextBox)control;
        // From here on you can use rtfChild as any other RichTextBox control.
    }
}
```

Of course, you can use this for any other type of control as well.

To check if the child form has a `RichTextBox`:

```
bool found = false;
foreach (Control control in this.ActiveMdiChild.Controls)
{
    if (control is RichTextBox)
    {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (found)
{
}
```

If you put this in a method that returns a `RichTextBox` control, then you can have the method check if the child form has a `RichTextBox`, and if so, return it, otherwise return `null`.

Comment: `if (control.GetType() == typeof(System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox)` is the same as `if (control is RichTextBox)`, as I found out ^^

Comment: Yes, but which is more convenient? ;-)